# E401 - Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid

Tags: node.js, npm

I tested with Azure Packages private NPM server and now want to revert back to using the standard NPM registry but when I do it complains.  I have tried everything I can think of and it is blocking me from doing any work now.  I'd really appreciate any help.

**The error**

- npm ERR! code E401
- npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.
- npm ERR! To correct this please trying logging in again with:
- npm ERR! npm login

If I check the log it is still, somehow, trying to find packages from Azure rather than the npm registry.

The Azure URL specified below doesnt exist in any .npmrc file or package-lock file I can find!

To be clear here I want to use the default NPM registry not Azure. e.g.

```
32 silly fetch manifest @types/angular@https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/***/***/_packaging/***.Common.UI/npm/registry/@types/angular/-/angular-1.6.45.tgz
```

**Steps I have taken**

- Deleted my local .npmrc file
- Deleted .npmrc file from my user profile
- Cleared NPM cache
- Cleared local node_modules folder
- npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
- npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com/
- Reinstalled node.js

In each case, running `npm install` still gives me the same error.

Please help!

Comment: I deleted the file package.lock.json and it back to work again

Answer (score 46):

#### .npmrc containing private repo credentials

- I had similar error. It turned out that I've saved some credentials for private repo on .npmrc file at the root of my home folder.
- So when I did npm install on my project, I get package-lock.json file contents appended with the private repo url. So this was the source of the error when deploying the project.
- What I did was to temporarily remove the .npmrc, delete package-lock.json, delete node_modules and re-run npm install.
- In my case the private repo details was not relevant for the project(so deleting .npmrc was not an issue)

Comment: This was exactly my issue, deleting package-lock.json and reinstalling node_modules has fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Remove ``.npmrc`` from home folder on mac

Comment: i did all of this except removing .npmrc and the error went away.

Comment: Nice! Removing just the `package-lock.json` solving the `code E401` problem for me.

Answer (score 15):

In my case , I just deleted the **package-lock.json file** and tried running `npm install`.

The error disappeared and all **packages** in **node-modules** were created.
This happened because in the previous **package-lock.json file** the **resolved** field had an address that was not for public access.

But my new **package-lock.json** **resolved** field looks like this:

```
"node_modules/@hapi/hoek": {
      "version": "9.3.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@hapi/hoek/-/hoek-9.3.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-/c6rf4UJlmHlC9b5BaNvzAcFv7HZ2QHaV0D4/HNlBdvFnvQq8RI4kYdhyPCl7Xj+oWvTWQ8ujhqS53LIgAe6KQ=="
    }.
```

Comment: I didn't even do npm login.

Answer (score 14):

Tried all the methods but Nothing worked for me. This steps solved my issue.

1. Delete the .npmrc file in your Users folder.

   `C:\Users\[your user name]`

2.Run this command in your project folder that has an .npmrc file in it:

```
npx vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc
```

Comment: just running the second one worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Check your package.json for the node version you should be using and make sure that you are using a compatible version with nvm or something. This has been consistently the reason I have seen this error lately on my own machine.

Comment: This is exactly my problem and I was able to fix it by upgrading my node version. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

if the issue exist entire system
check you global `.npmrc` file
for mac its `vim ~/.npmrc`

set config
`npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.com/"`

it will fix issue if problem with npmrc registry

if it happened for a single project it due to the propject .npmrc file.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple **npmrc** configurations and you've change one of them.

Change your **npmrc** to **default**

You can do this configuration for each one.

```
npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.com/"
```

Comment: This answer deserved more than 1 up vote. I had tried: 1) deleting packages-lock.json 2) updating personal .npmrc with latest PAT, 3) making sure my node is up to date, but nothing worked until I tried your comment by running npm config set registrty.  Thank you so much for your post.

Comment: Thanks Stevey I'm glad that this has helped you!

Answer (score 2):

The credentials in the .npmrc file have an expiration time. You need to regenerate these credentials.

Comment: The solution for me was to change the token located in .npmrc

Answer (score 1):

Above @kotana Sie worked for me. But there is no explanation so I would like to add that.

the errors mean that your access key to the private Azure DevOps npm repository has expired and npm can’t login to the repository using it.

To refresh the keys just run to acquire new:

```
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc
```

There is a known issue with sometimes that doesn't work and just says the keys “are already up to date” or “can’t get an authentication token…”:. To solve it delete the `C:\Users\<YourAccountName>\.npmrc` manually and repeat the process.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error for an individual repository. I got it when I ran `npm i`. The fix is:

1. Delete .npmrc for this repo
2. Delete package lock
3. Run npm i again
4. add back the deleted .npmrc

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue, Deleting the .npmrc and then doing npm login again solved my issue, it was located in the project directory

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers fixed it for me. I had an additional problem I didn't notice at first and solved it this way:

The project I was working on apparently used an old version of npm and node. So I downgraded both globally via `npm install -g npm@6.14.15` and `npm install -g node@16.18.0` (of course check which versions you need :)).

After that I ran `npm install` and it worked.